# "where xxx is not null and xxx / 2 < 4" : "is not null" seems to be executed after my operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

Here is my Entity Framework linq request (user already exists and my latitudes and longitudes are decimal) :

```
IQueryable<Event> dbQuery = context.Set<Event>()
                    .Where(e => e.GeoLat != null && e.GeoLong != null && user.Latitude != null && user.Longitude != null)
                    .Where(e => DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT("+e.GeoLong+" "+ e.GeoLat+")", 4326)
                        .Distance(DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(" + user.Longitude + " " + user.Latitude + ")", 4326)) < distanceKM*1000);
```

Here is the related part of the generated SQL request :

```
AND 
( 
  [Extent1].[GeoLat] IS NOT NULL 
) 
AND 
( 
  [Extent1].[GeoLong] IS NOT NULL 
) 
AND 
( 
  48,697161 
  /* @p__linq__1 */ 
  IS NOT NULL 
) 
AND 
( 
  2,189617 
  /* @p__linq__2 */ 
  IS NOT NULL 
) 
AND 
( 
  ( 
    geography::stpointfromtext(N'POINT(' + 
    CASE 
    WHEN ( 
        [Extent1].[GeoLong] IS NULL 
      ) 
      THEN 
      N'' 
      ELSE cast( [Extent1].[GeoLong] AS nvarchar(max)) 
    END 
    + N' ' + 
    CASE 
    WHEN ( 
        [Extent1].[GeoLat] IS NULL 
      ) 
      THEN 
      N'' 
      ELSE cast( [Extent1].[GeoLat] AS nvarchar(max)) 
    END 
    + N')', 4326).stdistance(geography::stpointfromtext(N'POINT(' + cast( 2.189617 AS nvarchar(max)) + N' ' + cast( 48.697161 AS nvarchar(max)) + N')', 4326))
  ) 
  < cast( 50 
  /* @p__linq__3 */ 
  * 1000 AS float) 
)
```

Here is the error I get :

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
>   System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 7 of the input. The input has ).

The error seems to tell me that the longitudes and latitudes values in POINT() are in fact empty string (')' at the position 7 => empty values).
I don't understand why I get this error since I tell to SQl to take only the rows where values are NOT NULL. It seems like SQL do the geography operations even on rows where values are NULL.

Could you help me to understand the reasons why ?

I use EF6.

Comment: T-SQL does not do shortcut evaluation, unlike C#. All parts of an `AND` are potentially evaluated. (This is not an answer, I have no idea how to write this correctly using EF -- but it does explain what you're seeing.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959347/string-isnullorempty-entity-framework-5

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does not perform short-circuit evaluation of `AND` operations. You might be able to resolve your issue by generating `IFNULL` statements using the `??` operator:

```
IQueryable<Event> dbQuery = context.Set<Event>()
.Where(e => e.GeoLat != null && e.GeoLong != null && 
            user.Latitude != null && user.Longitude != null)
.Where(e => 
  DbGeography.PointFromText(
      "POINT(" + (e.GeoLong ?? "1") + " " + (e.GeoLat ?? "1") + ")", 4326)
    .Distance(DbGeography.PointFromText(
      "POINT(" + (user.Longitude ?? "1") + " " + (user.Latitude ?? "1") + ")", 4326)
    ) < distanceKM * 1000)
```

**Edit**: If the issue is arising because the `NULL` values are being converted to an empty string, you could try converting them to an arbitrary integer value instead, such as 1. Since the other `Where` clause will filter out these rows, their computation does not matter, as long as it doesn't throw any error.

I understand that ideally these rows would be excluded from the `geography` operation in the first place, but that surprisingly is not as straightforward to achieve. The easiest approach is to allow the `geography` operation to proceed, then discard its results.

To really prevent it from being executed, you need to figure out how to get your LINQ query to emit a `CASE WHEN` clause.

Comment: Actually the empty string inside POINT() is the problem. The geography operation should not be executed on rows where long/lat values are NULL but I don't know how to achieve this !

Comment: I've managed to do so by using ternary operator x ? y : z where the geography operations are in y. That way they are executed only if x is true (x -> lat/long != null).