# Getting data from database by linq with filters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have table in database which contains some fields. For example:
filed1(int), filed2(int), filed3(int), Comment(string), UpdatedAt(datetime). Comment can by empty.

All records in database can be duplicated with this fields (of course withoud Id and updatedAt)
For example:

```
Id  | field1   | field2   | field3   | Comment| UpdatedAt
1   | 20       |56        | 3        |abc     |2024-02-01 08:00|
2   | 20       |56        | 3        |abc  def|2024-02-01 09:12|
3   | 21       |52        | 4        |test    |2024-02-01 11:00|
4   | 21       |52        | 4        |        |2024-02-01 15:12|
```

I need to get latest comment for field1, field2, field3 and check if comment is not empty. If comment is empty i can't get it from database.
For example. The latest comment for 20,56,3 is this record:

```
2   | 20       |56        | 3        |abc  def     |2024-02-01 09:12|
```

Latest comment for 21,52,4 is this record:

```
4   | 21       |52        | 4        |                   |2024-02-01 15:12|
```

Because this record contains empty comment i need skip this record.

So, when I get all latests comments for example record i expect only this record:

```
2   | 20       |56        | 3        |abc  def     |2024-02-01 09:12|
```

because this is latest record for this fields: 20,56,3 and it has comment value. And of course this record is latest for fields: 21, 52,4:

```
4   | 21       |52        | 4        |                   |2024-02-01 15:12|
```

but here is empty comment so i don't need this record.

I wrote query:

```
_context.myTable
            .GroupBy(_ => new { _.field1, _.field2, _.field3})
            .Select(_ => _.OrderByDescending(_ => _.UpdatedAt).FirstOrDefault())
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

This query getting all latest records with empty comments which is not expected.
When I tried this:

```
_context.myTable
            .GroupBy(_ => new { _.field1, _.field2, _.field3})
            .Select(_ => _.OrderByDescending(_ => _.UpdatedAt).FirstOrDefault())
            .Where(_ => _.Comment != string.Empty)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

it is not working because linq cant translate this query.

The simplest solution is get all records from first working query (with empty comments) and then write:

```
Where(_ => _.Comment != string.Empty)
```

but is not optimal solution. Because firsty I getting lod of records with empty comments in database and nextly I filtering it.
I looking for better and faster solution. I think it is possible to write this LINQ to get all which I need by only one shoot to database.

Comment: Which EF version are you using? Different major versions treat raw SQL queries differently

Comment: You should replace `string.Empty` with `""`. Maybe you need also to check for `null` values. see [string.IsNullOrEmpty + Entity Framework 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959347/string-isnullorempty-entity-framework-5)